# WP Plugin: Print javascript in header

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

[I am new to wordpress programming.]

I am developing a plugin. The plugin needs javascript code in header. In order to print the code only in header of plugin's setting page. I am unable to do that. I have referred [instructions here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/07/12/how-to-load-javascript-in-the-wordpress-admin)

The plugin works fine if javascript is printed using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-admin-javascript/)

I also tried to add code within body (after div) by below method....

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'ipn/javascript.php');
```

But that to did not work.

Check the plugin code....

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueued_assets' );

function my_enqueued_assets() {
wp_enqueue_script('Google_jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js');

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');
function my_plugin_menu() {
add_menu_page('My Plugin Settings', 'Plugin Settings', 'administrator', 'my-plugin-settings', 'my_plugin_settings_page', 'dashicons-admin-generic');
}

function my_plugin_settings_page() {
global $my_plugin_settings;

echo 'HTML Form code here';
add_action( "admin_head-{$my_plugin_settings}", 'my_admin_head_script' );
}
function my_admin_head_script() { ?>




// javascript code that i want to print in header

<script type="text/javascript">$(function() {
var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

$(document).on('click','#addScnt', function() {
        $('html code here').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
});

$(document).on('click','#remScnt', function() { 
        if( i > 2 ) {
                $(this).parents('p').remove();
                i--;
        }
        return false;
});
});</script>
// javascript code end



<?php }
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
echo 'CSS style here';
}
```

Comment: first you don't need to enqueue jquery again it is already enqueued by wordpress so you can remove that code... second you need to decide if you really want to print the script inline or enqueue it as a separate file as either are possibilities here.

Comment: @majick about 'enqueue jquery again'. yes i realized that later. I need to print it in header section "Only in" plugin settings page and "NOT" entire admin.

Comment: in `my_plugin_settings_page()` use `wp_register_script` to add your script only when this function is called

Comment: @majick "it is already enqueued by wordpress". for unknown reason, a function stops working without jquery-2.2.4.min.js

Comment: typically you would you `wp_enqueue_script` to enqueue the script as a file and put `array('jquery')` as the dependency argument to ensure it has loaded first, but if you are printing it inline, just put it in the `admin_footer` instead of in the header as jquery will have loaded by then.

Answer (score 0):

To only insert code into the header section in the admin area on single plugin pages you need to alter your `add_action()`function.

```
add_action('admin_head-pageof_thisplugin/thisplugin', 'thisplugin_adminhead');

function thisplugin_adminhead() {
    // here goes your content
    echo '<script>'
         .'/* ... */'
         .'</script>';
}
```

where `pageof_thisplugin/thisplugin`is the hook slug that returns out of the function that creates your page like `add_submenu_page()`, add_options_page`or`add_management_page`.

Source and further details in the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head-(plugin_page))

Comment: that did not work..

    add_action('admin_head-my_plugin_settings_page', 'thisplugin_adminhead');

    function thisplugin_adminhead() {
 echo script here
 
 }

Comment: your slug according to your first post should be my-plugin-settings not my_plugin_settings_page. The latter is the function name you are calling.

Comment: it was copy-paste mistake. I did actually try admin_head-my-plugin-settings

Comment: then probably the fact that you are using add_menu_page() is the problem. As the docs state: "Where HOOK_SUFFIX is the plugin's hook suffix as returned by add_submenu_page or one of its siblings add_options_page or add_management_page."